# Load handsontable from php array dynamically

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm using Handsontable to display data stored in php arrays. Then i parse them into javascript arrays :

```html
var i = 0;
<?php
  for($cpt=0; $cpt<count($nbmaxRows); $cpt++){  
?>    
 window['array'+i] = <?php echo json_encode(${'array'.$cpt}); ?>;
 i++;
<?php } ?>
```

Now i have array1, array2, array2, ..., arrayN filled with my datas and encoded for JS use.

Basically handsontable data are defined like this :

```
data = [
      ['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda', 'Mazda', 'Ford'],
      ['2012', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
      ['2013', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
      ['2014', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
      ['2015', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16],
      ['2016', 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16]
    ],
```

But how can i get this ?

```html
data = [
      [Col0, Col1, ..., ColN],
      [array0[0], array0[1], ..., array0[N]],
      [array1[0], array1[1], ..., array1[N]],
      [array2[0], array2[1], ..., array2[N]],
      [   ...   ,    ...   , ...,    ...   ],
      [arrayN[0], arrayN[1], ..., arrayN[N]]
    ],
```

I've looked everywhere but I dont find a way to fill dynamically my handsontable data :(

EDIT : I solved my problem ! I wanted to fill the data array when you don't know the number of inputs before. A simple push in a loop can fix this :

```html
for(var i = 0; i < nbmaxRows; i++) {
    data.push(
        [window['tab'+i][j], window['tab'+i][j+1], window['tab'+i][j+2], window['tab'+i][j+3], window['tab'+i][j+4], window['tab'+i][j+5], window['tab'+i][j+6], window['tab'+i][j+7]]);
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Not sure what you're asking and what php has to do with data parsing in JS. Are you asking how to parse arrays in JS? Or maybe how to load data into handsontable once it's loaded?

Comment: PHP is here only because i got my data from a previous html page. When i got them, i display the result in a handsontable array. What i'm asking is how can i load my data dynamically. It means the number of cells can change so i can't use the static way to fill the data array. I wrote in my post the result i want but i don't know how